# How to fade out Mediaplayer in background?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android studio apk, and while changing activies i want to fade out the song playing from Mediaplayer, but it instead waits for the fade to end and only then move to next activity. How do i make fade out and activity transition at the same time?

```
    float volume = 1f;
    while (volume > 0f) {
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
        volume = volume - 0.1f;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    MainActivity.mediaPlayer.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked up and found a solution

```
 private void fadeOut(final MediaPlayer mPlayer, final int duration) {
        final float deviceVolume = getDeviceVolume();
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            private float time = duration;
            private float volume = 0.0f;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mPlayer.start();
                    time -= 100;
                    volume = (deviceVolume * time) / duration;
                    mPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
                }
                if (time > 0){
                    h.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }else {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    }
 }

 public static float getDeviceVolume() {
    int volumeLevel = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    return (float) volumeLevel / maxVolume;
 }
```

You can use like this `fadeOut(MainActivity.mediaPlayer,5000);`